# Synchronizing React-native application integrated with the iOS Calendar using expo

Tags: react-native, icalendar

[image][image]I am trying to link my react native app with the iOS calendar. My app runs on expo and uses the react-native-calendar-strip. I've been searching to see how to make a start but not quite sure.Could you please guide me on how to do this?

below is the package that I used

https://github.com/BugiDev/react-native-calendar-strip

Comment: Please add some code as well